# URL Rewrite with Relative URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I most likely might be missing something. I found this URL Rewrite example on this great post: http://marisks.net/2017/05/14/changing-static-resource-urls-to-cdn-urls-with-url-rewrite/

My setup is identical. I have relative URLs in my code to which I want to rewrite them on-the-fly to point to my CDN.

```
<outboundRules>
  <clear />       
  <rule name="CDN" preCondition="CheckHTML" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
    <match filterByTags="Img, Link, Script, CustomTags" customTags="Video" pattern="(^(?!www\.|(?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/|[A-Za-z]:\\|\/\/).*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|mp4).*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://cdn.example.com{R:1}" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    </conditions>
  </rule>   
  <preConditions>
    <preCondition name="CheckHTML">
      <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
   </preCondition>
  </preConditions>
  <customTags>
    <tags name="Video">
      <tag name="source" attribute="src" />
    </tags>
  </customTags>           
</outboundRules>
```

This works great. **Except I need to fine-tune the rewrite to specific folders.** 
I know this sounds simple, but when I look at the Regex in the above script - I fail to see where I can place any sort of restriction on the words specifically in my relative URLs. Obviously I need to work harder at Regex. But any help is appreciated.

I need to only capture relative links with certain folders like /media or /css ("/media/media.mp4" or "/css/base.css").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed the issue. At least, it properly works for the folders I've set to rewrite and ignores the folders I have not specified. I'll do some more testing, but this works for now.

```
<rule name="CDN" preCondition="CheckHTML" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match filterByTags="Img, Link, Script, CustomTags" customTags="Video" pattern="(^(\/(media|css)+)*\/.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://cdn.example.com{R:0}" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

The PreConditions and Tags are the same throughout.

Updated the Regex:

```
(^\/media\/.*)|(^\/css\/.*)
```